# How to reference only the first object in indexPathsForVisibleRows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What I'm trying to do is detect which sections of a `UITableView` are visible, and then change the date of a calendar based on which are visible.

The issue is that there are typically multiple sections viewable at the same time, and I only want to change the date based on the first section index that appears in `visibleRowIndexes`, not all of them.

Here's my current implementation (Note: I run this function in cellForRowAtIndexPath):

```
-(BOOL)whatSectionsAreVisible {

    NSArray *visibleRowIndexes = [self.agendaTable indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    for (NSIndexPath *index in visibleRowIndexes) {
        NSNumber *daySection = @(index.section);

        static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
        if(!dateFormatter){
            dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; // Read the documentation for dateFormat
        }

        // Here is where I will map every index.section to an NSDate
        NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [comps setDay:daySection.intValue]; // <<== Extract int from daySection
        [comps setMonth:6];
        [comps setYear:2015];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

        // Update the day selected according to visible section
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kJTCalendarDaySelected" object:date];

        // Store currentDateSelected
        [self.calendar setCurrentDateSelected:date];

        NSLog(@"The visible section has an index of: %ld", (long)index.section);

        if (index.section == 0) {
            NSLog(@"index.row is indeed 0");
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I tried doing something like `NSNumber *daySection = @(index[0].section);` instead of `NSNumber *daySection = @(index.section);`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a loop if you just want the first visible row. Get the first object of `visibleRowIndexes` as an NSIndexPath. Then get the section from that.

Comment: I tried setting it like so: `NSIndexPath *firstIndex = visibleRowIndexes[0];` and then using it later like this: `[comps setDay:firstIndex.intValue];`, but this gives me an error stating `property intValue not found on object of type NSIndexPath`.

Comment: @ghobs91 instead of `firstIndex.intValue`, use `firstIndex.section`.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexPathsForVisibleRows` method returns the index paths in ascending order. So, get rid of the `for` loop and execute the code in it only for the first object:

```
NSArray *visibleRowIndexes = [self.agendaTable indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *index = [visibleRowIndex objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: That gives me an error stating that `NSArray` doesn't declare the selector `objectAt`.

Comment: Sorry, typo - should be objectAtIndex:

Comment: "returns the index paths in ascending order" – is that guaranteed though? It's not documented as far as I can see.